# How to deploy Visual C++ redistributables in WiX using Burn

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

We just migrated our installer from [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 2.x to WiX 3.6 and started using [Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn). Previously, we were installing the [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_versions) redistributable by including the .msm files from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules` to our [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer). Those files are always in sync with the one we use to build our product (they are updated frequently by Microsoft to include security fixes).

Now, we would like to have the Visual C++ redistributable downloaded only if required by using the Burn framework. However, Burn does not define a `MsmPackage` element to place inside `Chain`.

What is the best approach for deploying Visual C++ redistributable using Burn?

Comment: What about creating a "vc redist-msi" including only the vc redist msm file?

Comment: That was the approach I was thinking, but Bob's answer seems to involve less management.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merge modules can only be merged into an .msi; they can't be installed independently. You can use `ExePackage` to install the appropriate vcredist*.exe.

Comment: Thank you Bob.  I just found more on the topic here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do:

1. Create an MSI project that only includes the merge modules you need.
2. Clamp the MSI package version number, product code and upgrade code.
3. Use the MSI in your bundle.

Now 2) will ensure that in upgrade scenarious the MSI won't be installed, or if it is an external payload, it won't be downloaded.

The problem with packaging `vcredist*.exe` is that some user might think that it is an independent install and uninstall it and break your application.